# Create a Dev branch and push the code from local to Dev

Tags: github, terminal

I have a GitHub Repo (master branch) and also different code done in local folder (with subfolders).

Now I want to use that existing repo and create a Dev branch and push all folders and files (`git add .`) to that Dev branch.

What is the proper way to do via terminal (commands)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/**USER**/**repo**.git

git branch dev

git checkout -b dev

git add . 

git commit -m “create dev branch”

git push -u origin dev
```

Comment: Thanks for the flow.. Should it be `git checkout -b dev` for the 3rd step?

Answer (score 2):

If your local git does not point to the remote repository, use this to add a new remote server:

```
git remote add origin {insert_repository_url}
```

If you already have that set up, though, keep reading.
You need to create a new branch locally:

```
git checkout -b dev_branch_name
```

The `-b` tells git to create a new branch.
After that, all your changes will be taken to the new branch, so you can simply:

```
git add .
git commit -m "my new changes"
```

All your changes are now committed locally. In order to push them to your remote git repository:

```
git push -u origin dev_branch_name
```

This will also create the new branch on the remote repository and set your local branch to track that one.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!